# Finding the reduction by percentage

Tags: algebra-precalculus

So i kinda think i have figured this out, i'm not very good at math, and need a formula to figure out some stats for a game i'm playing.

I have a Weapon with a reload speed of X sec.. however, i also have a modifier attached, that will make the weapon reload faster by +Y%

i made this formula, mostly by guessing, as i got no clue what i am doing.

```
100/(100+Y)*X
```

the results i am getting looks right to me, but is the formula ok?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is subtle.  If you say you reload faster by $50\%$, does that mean you need $\frac 23$ the time to reload or $\frac 12$ the time?  The first is like you are running a race and increase your speed by $50\%$, the second is that you take $50\%$ less time to load.  For the first, your reload time becomes $\frac X{1+\frac Y{100}}=\frac {100X}{100+Y}$, which is probably what you meant to say.  Your expression is ambiguous because the $X$ could be in the numerator or denominator-please watch parentheses when using the fraction slash.  For the second, your reload time becomes $X(1-\frac Y{100})$

Comment: thanks, i think i understand what you mean by that, i got myself confused, as i had no idea of what i was doing, or what i wanted.

i think the thing i am going for, is if the speed is 200%, it should be the double speed, by that i mean the time is halved of what it is at 100%

Comment: so it was solution 1 i was looking for, thanks again for the good explanation :)

Answer (score 0):

Reloading faster means the time taken to reload is shorter.

The new time required to reload = old value * (1 + change%) = X * (1 - Y%)